# How to create a new Workbook for each 'new' value in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new spreadsheet for each *new* value that is in a specific column.

Example data attached:

[image: example data]

Currently, I have to take this data and push it through a formula and what the formula puts out, is copied and pasted into a Notepad file.

I want to have it make a new spreadsheet for each *new* value in the D column so that with the example, there would be two files created and have all of the rows for each one with it. So it would end up with one file for '86373' containing the 13 rows and one file for '86376' containing the 2 rows.

I am new to writing VBA and this is outside of my expertise so I currently have no code to share for this portion of the macro.. Any help is appreciated!

Here is where I am at with my current code:

```
    Dim ShipmentField As Range
    Dim ShipmentNum As Range
    Dim NewWSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WSheet As Worksheet
    Dim WSheetFound As Boolean
    Dim ShipmentWSheet As Worksheet
    
    x.Worksheets("UPS_CSV_EXPORT").Activate 'x is set to the workbook that contains the date. Using macro in separate workbook.
    Set ShipmentWSheet = Worksheets("UPS_CSV_EXPORT")
    Set ShipmentField = ShipmentWSheet.Range("D2", ShipmentWSheet.Range("D2").End(xlDown))
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ShipmentNum In ShipmentField
    
        For Each WSheet In x.Worksheets
            If WSheet.Name = ShipmentNum Then
                WSheetFound = True
                Exit For
            Else
                WSheetFound = False
            End If
        Next WSheet
        
        If WSheetFound Then
            ShipmentNum.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ShipmentNum.Value).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            
            Else
            
            Set NewWSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=x.Sheets(x.Sheets.Count))
            Debug.Print ShipmentNum
            NewWSheet.Name = ShipmentNum
            
            ShipmentWSheet.Range("A1", ShipmentWSheet.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A1")
            
            ShipmentNum.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=NewWSheet.Range("A2")
        
        End If
    Next ShipmentNum
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I am getting a "subscript out of range" error on the line: `ShipmentNum.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets(ShipmentNum.Value).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)`

Thanks,
Colvin

Comment: It should also be noted that the number in the D column will change everyday and will have minimum of 1 different number but could have up to 50. (Pictured is just today's numbers).

Comment: Appreciate the comment @braX, this portion of the macro is still blank while I try to research how to even do this.. Apologizes for the lack of code but if you have any helpful resources that I can look into to find the answer of how to do this, that would be fantastic..

Comment: Already answered there using pivot tables and some vba
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63456421/vba-make-one-sheet-into-multiple-workbooks/63458648#63458648

Comment: @pascalb, I'd like to try and get it to a point that would be fully automated by the macro without having whoever runs it have to do anything.

I have updated my post with my current code..

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Sub Copy_With_AutoFilter1()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim FilterCriteria As String
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim rng As Range

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria :
    'This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    'Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
    My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=Netherlands"

    'If you want to filter on a cell value you can use this, use "<>" for the opposite
    'This example uses the activecell value
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & ActiveCell.Value

    'This will use the cell value from A2 as criteria
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Range("A2").Value

    ''If you want to filter on a Inputbox value use this
    'FilterCriteria = InputBox("What text do you want to filter on?", _
     '                              "Enter the filter item.")
    'My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & FilterCriteria

    'Check if there are not more then 8192 areas(limit of areas that Excel can copy)
    CCount = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(1).Cells.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If CCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas:" _
             & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
             & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to worksheet"
    Else
        'Add a new Worksheet
        Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index))

        'Ask for the Worksheet name
        sheetName = InputBox("What is the name of the new worksheet?", _
                             "Name the New Sheet")

        On Error Resume Next
        WSNew.Name = sheetName
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Change the name of sheet : " & WSNew.Name & _
                 " manually after the macro is ready. The sheet name" & _
                 " you fill in already exists or you use characters" & _
                 " that are not allowed in a sheet name."
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Copy/paste the visible data to the new worksheet
        My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
        With WSNew.Range("A1")
            ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
            ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Select
        End With

        ' If you want to delete the rows that you copy, also use this
        ' With My_Range.Parent.AutoFilter.Range
        '     On Error Resume Next
        '     Set rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count) _
        '               .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        '     On Error GoTo 0
        '     If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Delete
        ' End With

    End If

    'Close AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    If Not WSNew Is Nothing Then WSNew.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You can find more info here.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_1.htm